# Journey Builder: How to use Wait by Attribute using Contact Data

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have built a journey which send an email the day before of an event. To do this, I have chosen a Wait by Attribute using Contact Data due to the date of the event may change. The journey can contains different events and one person may attent to different events.

Each Event have different Attendees (which contains contact information) so, when an Attendee is injected to the journey, the journey should know which event is related with it. Unfortunately, it doesn't happen and the Wait by Attribute doesn't work properly and send the email without having into account the start date/time of the event.

How can I know which information is using the wait by attribute? How can I ensure that the journeys will work properly? We should create a journey for each event?

I attach different images of the journey:

[image]

[image]

Can you help me?

Thank you,
Anna

Answer (score 0):

If there is a 1: N in the contact data this will not work as you have noticed. My recommendation is to bring `StartDateTime` into the entry source DE and use Journey Data

Comment: Hi @EazyE,

Thanks for your answer. The issue is that the StartDateTime may change and for this reason I can't use Journey Data. Is there any way to update Journey Data with that information?Thank you so much

Comment: The start date could change within the one hour you injected them and they hit the wait step?  Once they hit the wait step the end date won’t change. You may want to design a process that injects them one day prior to the start date and not worry about the wait step

Comment: Hi @EazyE,
The start date could change until 1 day before the event. Maybe it is better to create an automation and, as you have said, inject the attendees one day before the start date.
Thank you so much,